# Ecto Cannot Find Repo In Project

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to add Ecto to my project. It's a standard project not generated with `--s` to add a supervisor.

So far I've used

`mix ecto.gen.repo -r MyApp.Repo`

Which generates it just fine.

In my `config/dev.exs` I have the following:

```
config :my_app,
  ecto_repos: [MyApp.Repo]

config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  database: System.get_env("DATABASE_NAME"),
  username: System.get_env("DATABASE_USER"),
  password: System.get_env("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
  hostname: System.get_env("DATABASE_HOST"),
  port: System.get_env("DATABASE_PORT")
```

In `myapp/repo.ex` I have:

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :my_app
end
```

However, when I go to create the repo with

```
mix ecto.create --env=dev
```

I get

```
warning: could not find Ecto repos in any of the apps: [:my_app].

You can avoid this warning by passing the -r flag or by setting the
repositories managed by those applications in your config/config.exs:

config :eos, ecto_repos: [...]
```

This also occurs if I omit the `--env` flag.

I am hopelessly lost. This is consistent with the getting started guide (minus the supervisor stuff which it did not indicate was required), and I'm stalled out here. Can anyone help me sort this out? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure `config/dev.exs` is being loaded in `config/config.exs`? Do you have a line like `import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"` near the end?

Comment: Wow! I didn't know I needed to do this! Post the answer up so I can check it off. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elixir only loads the config declarations in `config/config.exs` by default. The `<env>.exs` convention used by many projects including Phoenix requires the following line to be added to the end of `config/config.exs` in order to load the correct exs file:

```
import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"
```